# laravel eloquent where like operator for integer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

What I'm working on right now is a generate report and I have multiple fields in one page which are  address,date,gender and vaccine

What I want is even if the address is empty and i inputted a gender it will stillretrieve all of the specific gender that has been selected and if the user has not inputted anything on the fields it will automatically retrieve all the records. So what I did is this

In my Controller

```
if (!$request->input) {
    $request->input = "";
}
if (!$request->vaccines) {

    $vaccine_id = "";
}else{
    $vaccine_id = $request->vaccines;
}
if (!$request->month) {

    $newDate = " ";
}else{
    $newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($request->month));
}
if (!$request->gender) {

    $request->gender = "";
}

$patient = Patient::where('patient_address', 'like' ,'%' . $request->input)->where('patient_sex', 'like' ,'%' . $request->gender)->whereHas('users', function($q) use($vaccine_id){
        $q->where('vaccine_id',  $vaccine_id);
    })->get();
```

So I used `LIKE` operator so that even if the patient address was empty it will still return results unlike `=` operator it will automatically return false and end the rest of the `WHERE` clause. string type columns are working just fine like the patient address and the sex. But I just found out that you cant use a `LIKE` operator on integer. So if i use `=` on the vaccine_id, if the condition is false it will not retrieve all the data on the database automatically unlike the `LIKE` operator.

Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$query = Patient::where('patient_address', 'like' ,'%' . $request->input)->where('patient_sex', 'like' ,'%' . $request->gender);

if($vaccine_id != "") {
    $query->whereHas('users', function($q) use($vaccine_id){
        $q->where('vaccine_id',  $vaccine_id);
    });
}

$patient = $query->get();
```